# C++/CLI .Net 3.5 build has a dependency on .Net 4

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI project which I am building in VS 2012, targeting the `3.5` framework. When I try to use it I get an error (abbreviated):

```
warning MSB3258: The primary reference "my.dll" could not be resolved because it 
has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" 
than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
```

If I look in the External Dependencies list of the C++ project, I can see a bunch of `System.* assemblies` and `mscorlib` at version `2.0`, as I expect, plus mscorlib at version `4.0`.

Any ideas where this stray 4.0 dependency is coming from, or how to find out where it is coming from?

Comment: This might help http://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com/

Comment: Not really; it tells me my .dll has a dependency on mscorlib 4.0, but I already knew that, it does not seem to give me any clue as to where that is being introduced.

Comment: You will have to take a closer look at the reference assemblies of your project.  And the .resx files.

Comment: Hans, at risk of being downvoted for not doing my homework, what sort of thing should I be having a closer look for? I don't have any .resx files.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a known "feature" of VS2012:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780602/compiling-c-clr-dll-in-vs-2012-targeting-net-2-0-introduces-indirect-dependency-on-net-4-0